# How do you throttle a REST API using many Heroku dynos?

Tags: rest, api, heroku, api-design, throttling

I configured my REST API throttling, accepting 10 requests max per minute.
It works as expected in a local environment.

However, when deploying on Heroku, this throttling is applied on a dyno basis.
Since the routing to select a dynos is kind of random, this means for example if I have 2 dynos,
an error can occur between the 11th and the 20th request (this often happens around 16 or 17 requests actually).

How to have a clean throttling with deterministic rates, that does not change when dyno config changes, on Heroku?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must currently be storing the throttling data into memory. You need to store that in a shared database, such as Redis.
If you read and write the value to/from that database every time, it will be shared among dynos and you will have something a lot more reliable.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that makes sense. Maybe a silly question, but is it going to slow down API requests since it requires reading/writing in an external DB? How do you ensure the API still works if the Redis server goes down?

Comment: Yes, it's slightly going to reduce your response time. And ensuring the API still works if the redis server goes offline depends on how you write your code. You can get your code to ignore the throttling if redis is throwing errors for example.